# MYSQL multiple INNER JOIN retrieve every information

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

i want to run the following query in my script but it won't work correctly.
I'm not getting any errors, it just selects the data from hs_data correct (and everything) but from hs_download_links it only retrieved as much data as there are entries in hs.images.

The goal of this query should be to get any entry from hs_data. If there's information related to these entries in hs_download_links or hs_images it should get them as well.

```
                    SELECT
                        h.hacks_ID, h.hacks_Name, h.hacks_Name_Full, 
                    h.hacks_Version, h.hacks_Description, h.hacks_AddDate,
                     h.hacks_Type, SUM(dl.link_count) AS link_count, i.image_NameThumb
                    FROM
                        hs_data h
                    LEFT JOIN
                        (hs_download_links dl CROSS JOIN hs_images i)
                    ON 
                        ((dl.link_hackID = h.hacks_ID AND i.image_HackID = h.hacks_ID)
                    OR 
                    (dl.link_hackID = h.hacks_ID AND i.image_HackID is NULL) 
                    OR
                    (dl.link_hackID is NULL AND i.image_HackID = h.hacks_ID)
                    OR 
                    (dl.link_hackID is NULL AND i.image_HackID is NULL) )
                    GROUP BY 
                        h.hacks_ID
                    ORDER BY link_count DESC
```

Would be great if you guys could help me, much thanks :)

Comment: Say you have 3 download links and 7 images for a record in `hs_data`. How many records do you want returned in the resultset for that `hs_data`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write this as:

```
SELECT h.hacks_ID, h.hacks_Name, h.hacks_Name_Full, 
       h.hacks_Version, h.hacks_Description, h.hacks_AddDate,
       h.hacks_Type, SUM(dl.link_count) AS link_count, i.image_NameThumb
FROM hs_data h LEFT JOIN
     hs_download_links dl
     on dl.link_hackID = h.hacks_ID LEFT JOIN
     hs_images i
     on i.image_HackID = h.hacks_ID
GROUP BY h.hacks_ID
ORDER BY link_count DESC;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `cross join`, but it seems unnecessarily confusing.  You can chain `left outer join`s together.  They still keep all the rows in the first table.

By the way, your select has a dangling `i.image_NameThumb`.  That means that only one such value will appear.  If there are multiple values, you might want to use `group_concat()`.  Or even `min()` or `max()` just to clarify the intent of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of download links and the first image, if any, for each record in `hs_data`:

```
SELECT  d.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    hs_download_links dl
        WHERE   dl.link_hackId = d.hacks_Id
        ),
        (
        SELECT  i.image_NameThumb
        FROM    hs_images i
        WHERE   i.image_hackId = d.hacks_Id
        ORDER BY
                image_NameThumb
        LIMIT 1
        )
FROM    hs_data d
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me but I'll youse the solution from Gordon_Linoff 'cause I can read it better :>